property name <<speed>> invalid. (M16)
I'm trying to call 3 files in my dashboard.qml file : speed, RPM and EngCoolTemp. The RPM and EngCoolTemp are called correctly with no error but when i call speed it gives me the "property name <> invalid. (M16)" error; here's the code:
import QtQuick 6.2
import QtQuick.Controls 6.2

Item {
    id: id_dashboard

    // To create data for demonstration purposes
    property int countSpeed: 0
    property int countRPM: 0
    property int countEngCoolTemp: 0

    Timer {
        id: id_timer
        repeat: true
        interval: 1000
        running: true

        onTriggered: {
            updateSpeed();
            updateEngCoolTemp();
            updateRPM();
        }
    }

    // Speed Gauge
    Rectangle {
        id: id_speedArea

        anchors {
            horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        }
        width: parent.width * 0.4
        height: width
        color: "black"
        radius: width / 2
        z: 1

        speed {
            id: id_speed
            anchors.fill: id_speedArea
            anchors.margins: id_speedArea.width * 0.025
        }
    }

    // RPM Gauge
    Rectangle {
        id: id_RPMArea

        anchors {
            bottom: id_speedArea.bottom
        }
        x: parent.width / 20
        width: parent.width * 0.35
        height: width
        color: "black"
        radius: width / 2

        RPM {
            id: id_RPM
            anchors.fill: id_RPMArea
            anchors.margins: id_RPMArea.width * 0.025
        }
    }

    // Engine Coolant Temperature Gauge
    Rectangle {
        id: id_EngCoolTempArea

        anchors {
            bottom: id_speedArea.bottom
        }
        x: parent.width - parent.width / 2.5
        width: parent.width * 0.35
        height: width
        color: "black"
        radius: width / 2

        EngCoolTemp {
            id: id_EngCoolTemp
            anchors.fill: id_EngCoolTempArea
            anchors.margins: id_EngCoolTempArea.width * 0.025
        }
    }

    // Divider
    Rectangle {
        id: id_divider

        anchors {
            bottom: id_speedArea.bottom
            left: id_RPMArea.horizontalCenter
            right: id_EngCoolTempArea.horizontalCenter
        }
        height: id_RPMArea.width / 2
        color: "black"
        z: -1
    }

    function updateSpeed() {
        countSpeed++;
        if (countSpeed % 2 === 0) {
            id_speed.value = 0;
        } else {
            id_speed.value = 280;
        }
    }

    function updateEngCoolTemp() {
        countEngCoolTemp++;
        if (countEngCoolTemp % 3 === 0) {
            if (id_EngCoolTemp.value === 0) {
                id_EngCoolTemp.value = 120;
            } else {
                id_EngCoolTemp.value = 50;
            }
        }
    }

    function updateRPM() {
        countRPM++;
        if (countRPM % 2 === 0) {
            if (id_RPM.value === 0) {
                id_RPM.value = 7000;
            } else {
                id_RPM.value = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}


how can i solve this problem.and thanks!
i tried asking chatgpt but it didn't give me a direct solution

Since you didn't provide a complete example, I can't tell what speed is, but I'm wondering if it would work if you renamed it so it started with a capital letter instead of lowercase?

Yes there's something Really Wrong with your Speed Guard care to explain what's going on?

What @JarMan said, re: upper and lower case. Your error said that it was an invalid 'property', but within your example, it appears as a component. Properties begin with lowercase, and components begin with uppercase. I suspect that Qt is interpreting your component (if that is what you meant it to be) to be a property because of the lower case.

actually yes i am using speed as a component, but whenever i write Speed with an uppercase S it gives me this error: "unknown component. (M300)", Ps: the file name is "speed.qml" the s is not uppercase could that be the problem ?also i have three other errors like this throught the project .

Yes, you need to rename the .qml file to use uppercase as well.

@MohamedsadokJomaa See the documentation: the name of the file corresponds to the name of the component, and since components must begin with uppercase letters, their file names should too.
